# Simple classification in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, export-to-csv

I am trying to develop a simple classification program using scikit-learn. I want to pull in my set of tsv values, save them in an array. Then, save a csv containing the first value of my tsv from above and simply a random 1 or 0. So it will be output to the csv as follows:

```
tsvValue1, random1or0 eg
string123, 0
foo234, 1
```

I have all the code (nearly) separately, my problem is fitting it all together.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
import pandas as p

loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')

def main():
    traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('../data/train.tsv'))[:,2])
    testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('../data/test.tsv'))[:,2])
    y = np.array(p.read_table('../data/train.tsv'))[:,-1]

    X_all = traindata + testdata

    # What can I do below? What can I use to export to csv
    # properly with an appended 1 or 0 value below ?

    from random import randint
    randomInt = randint(0,1) #Inclusive    
    testfile = p.read_csv(
        '../data/test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
    pred_df = p.DataFrame(testdata, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
    pred_df.to_csv('test.csv')
    print ("your random file has been created..")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

UPDATE :
Standard format of input tsv file:

```
foo1                       foo2   foo3   foo4   fooN
RelevantString123123123
RelevantString456456456
RelevantString789789789
```

Format of desired resulting csv:

```
RelevantString123123123,1
RelevantString456456456,0
RelevantString789789789,1
```

The second 1 or 0 in the csv file being ranzomly generated.

Comment: If `values` is the list of values for `tsvValue1` column then `zip(values, (random.randint(0, 1) for _ in itertools.count()))` will give you the pairs `(value, zero_or_one)`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Rho Thanks for the response. I have tried to write the code to do this, but I cannot contort in a way so it will compile correctly to output a csv of the form value, zero_or_one. Any chance you can help me on this please?

Comment: Could you provide a sample (just few lines) of the input files and the expected output in the csv file?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with scikit-learn and machine learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the file `input.tsv` with the content (separated by tabs):

```
foo1                       foo2   foo3   foo4   fooN
RelevantString123123123
RelevantString456456456
RelevantString789789789
```

This shows how to get the output you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('input.tsv', sep='\t')
>>> df['value'] = pandas.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=len(df)), index=df.index)
>>> df.to_csv('output.csv', cols=['foo1', 'value'], index=False)
```

The `output.csv` content is:

```
foo1,value
RelevantString123123123,1
RelevantString456456456,0
RelevantString789789789,0
```